# If $\Sigma$ is finitely satisfiable, can both $\Sigma \cup \{ \phi\}$ and $\Sigma \cup \{ \neg \phi\}$ be finitely satisfiable?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

In propositional logic, if $\Sigma$ is finitely satisfiable, can both $\Sigma \cup \{ \phi\}$ and $\Sigma \cup \{ \neg \phi\}$ be finitely satisfiable?

I proved that at least one of $\Sigma \cup \{ \phi\}$ and $\Sigma \cup \{ \neg \phi\}$ must be finitely satisfiable, but could both be?

Comment: $\left\{P\right\}$ is satisfiable (hence finitely satisfiable), and so are $\left\{P, Q\right\}$ and $\left\{P, \lnot Q\right\}$

Comment: Certainly both could be. To show that, all you need is an example. Simplest is to let $\Sigma$ be empty.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I don't understand your argument. Finite satisfiability of $\Sigma$ implies that _every_ finite subset of $\Sigma$ is finitely satisfiable.

Comment: @nothing12345: so? why do you think that defeats my example? all the sets I gave are *obviously* satisfiable (and hence finitely satisfiable).

Comment: Perhaps you mean to assume that $\Sigma$ is infinite. But you did not say so; hence the simple examples André and I gave. For an infinite example, take $\Sigma$ to be $\left\{P, P\lor P, P\lor P\lor P, \ldots\right\}$ and then take the union with $Q$ and its negation.

Comment: @symplectomorphic OK, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course both are satisfiable:

Recall that a set of sentences $S$ is **complete** if, for every sentence $\varphi$, either $S \vdash \varphi$ or $S \vdash \neg \varphi$.

All we need to show is that not every finite satisfiable set is complete. That is, as observed in the comments, it suffices give a counterexample of an incomplete finite satisfiable set. And for any signature you have, there are certainly many of them:

- $\emptyset$ is (vacuously) finite satisfiable, but incomplete.
- $\{\alpha\}$ is finite satisfiable, but incomplete.
- $\{\alpha, \alpha\rightarrow \alpha\}$ is finite satisfiable, but incomplete and so on

For any arbitrary sentences $\alpha, \beta$ of your language.